# How to return to deleted verison Library ,manage version

Tags: google-apps-script

I play with the concept of a "library" of Google Apps Script.

I have 2000 non-spreadsheet google doc documents with a library call script

I created a library called "biblio". I set up its initial version (it awarded version # 1). I erroneously deleted this version of the library by clicking the cross "x", so no more version.

When I add a version it puts the version number at # 2.

I can not go back and I have my 2000 google documents that load the version # 1 disappeared at the opening and it does not take the version to # 2 which is the only one to be available. I chose this version (I had no choice).

```
Function oninstall () {
   OnOpen ();
 }

Function onOpen () {
   Biblio.oninstall ();
 }
```

[Manage Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgv1H.png)

My question: Is it possible to load the latest version of the library automatically here version to # 2? Instead of selecting each time

Or more simply,
Can we go back and recreate a version # 1: so no change of version of library?

I also tried to run the counter versions of scripts, I thought maybe after the version at # 99 it would start again # 1 and well no. I also try # 999 to see if that pass to #1
Does setting a new version have any effect? I miss something?

Comment: in development mode it can take the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to load the latest version of the library automatically here version to # 2?

You have to set the version, try the [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) to select the version you want to use.

> Click on the Versions dropdown and select a version of this library that you want to use.
> [image]

#### Or more simply, Can we go back and recreate a version # 1: so no change of version of library?

Unfortunately once the version is deleted it cannot be recovered.

[image]

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Thank you ... My problem is that I already have 2000 documents that call my library in Version # 1 which was deleted by mistake and therefore no longer finds it.
The work is tedious and painful to have edited each script on 2000 documents, manage the library and change Version # 1 which no longer exists anymore then check out Version # 2 the latest version.

Can we do this work with a script
Can the solution is to publish an add-ons that I wish to be for my personal use for now
How can I do ?

Comment: Perhaps the solution consist to obtain the Library version and change to the last version by a new script ?[link](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/libraryinfo_italic_ **bold** `code`